# How to join several mp3s (wavs) on server?

Tags: php, mp3

I'm looking for a possibility to join several audio files in one on the server.

**Example:** `audio_01.mp3 / 33sec + audio_02.mp3 / 22sec = audio_03.mp3 / 55sec`

Server - Linux based, my main language is PHP (just in case)

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are the files wav or mp3 ?

Comment: let's consider both ways if there's a difference between joining wavs and mp3s. Initially it was planned to use mp3s but I'd love to learn how to merge wavs also

Comment: why downvote??? I asked a normal question. then found an answer and posted it below. what was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USING FFMPEG**

This will concatenate two mp3 files, and the resulting metadata will be that of the first file:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -acodec copy output.mp3
```

This is because, for ffmpeg, the whole "concat:" part is a single "input file", and its metadata will be of the first concatenated file. If you want to use metadata from the second file instead, you have to add it as a dummy input file and map its metadata to that of the output:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -i file2.mp3 -acodec copy test.mp3 -map_metadata 0:1
```

If you want to construct your metadata from the two metadatas, you'll have to do it by hand. You can dump a file's metadata with

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp3 -f ffmetadata file1.metadata
```

After dumping both metadatas and constructing new metadata, you can add it to the output file with -metadata, and you can disable metadata copying by setting a -map_metadata mapping from a negative input file number. This sets a name value and no other metadata:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -acodec copy -metadata "title=Some Song" test.mp3 -map_metadata 0:-1
```

Comment: yea - this would be the right way to do it.
works like a charm. 
DON'T FORGE TO ADD PATH TO FFMPEG (i.e shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "concat:001.mp3|002.mp3" -i 002.mp3 -acodec copy test.mp3 -map_metadata 0:1');